# SQL Bit operation, change second last bit to 0

Tags: mysql, sql, bit, operation

i have a lot of rows with an bigint(length 20) and i have to change every second last bit to 0.
For example i have: 0101 1011 and the result i need is: 0101 1001
The Problem is, the numbers are "random" and i can't calcuate -2(10).

Comment: When you say your value is `01011011` do you mean it is 93 or it is 1,011,011?

Comment: 0101 1011 mean 93.

Comment: Oops I meant 91... :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the bitwise AND operator ([`&`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and)), `AND`ing with NOT 2 (created using the bitwise inversion operator ([`~`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-invert))) to get your results e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE test (num BIGINT(20));
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(4),
(91),
(9223372036854775807);
SELECT num, num & ~2 FROM test;
```

Output:

```
num                     num & ~2
4                       4
91                      89
9223372036854775807     9223372036854775805
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7f372895a51a631493e81c665f63c89d)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Bitwise And" operator to change the bit.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017